# lambda non static C#

Tags: c#, lambda, static, uwp

I am trying to dynamically bind action handlers to radio buttons in UWP with a lambda function:

```
private void populateMenu(ListBar lb)
{
    foreach (var item in lb.Groups)
    {
        leftMenuStackBar.Children.Add(ListBar.rbGrp(item));

        foreach (var LItem in item.Items)
        {
            var radioButton = ListBar.rb(LItem);
            radioButton.Click += (o, i) =>
            {
                loadFromMenuClick(LItem.Transl, frame);
            };

        leftMenuStackBar.Children.Add(radioButton);
    }
}
```

the compiler says that the function "loadFromMenuclick" has to be static. In this function I want to use the Frame.Navigate function:

```
public void loadFromMenuClick(string test, Frame f)
{
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(Themes.AbstractView), test);
}
```

I gave it the "Frame f" object, because I had this error before, but the way that the navigate function works, it is better to use the static Frame.Navigate in stead of f.Navigate.

When I try to use the Frame.Navigate, I get the "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property 'Frame.Navigate(Type, object)'" error...

How do I get this to work?

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: You have `Frame` object `f` not used. If you don't need that why you have passed it?

Comment: I added it before to get rid of this error, but the navigating part wasn't working. I tried it with another handler that was not static and used the Frame.Navigate function. That worked. I am now trying to figure out how to do it with a lambda...

Comment: @Bart: Microsoft courses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your "test" string. At the moment your eventhandler is called, there's no reference to `LItem.Transl`. Since we don't know what's in that item and how it's linked to a `RadioButton`, I'll continue my reply with the assumption that the string value of `LItem.Transl` is also stored in the `Tag` property of the `RadioButton`. This is the code for your loop where you attach the eventhandler

```
var radioButton = ListBar.rb(LItem);
radioButton.Tag = LItem.Transl; // maybe this is in .Text as well?
radioButton.Click += (o, i) => loadFromMenuClick(o);
```

Your function will be:

```
private void loadFromMenuClick(object sender)
{
    RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) sender;
    frame.Navigate(typeof (Themes.AbstractView), radioButton.Tag?.ToString());
}
```